# What's the best way to implement requests with tokens clearly?

Tags: flutter

I have screen with tabs and each screen implements AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin. When I navigate to this screen(with tabs), each tab in initState fetches data from server like that:

```
fetchData()async{
  final token = await getToken();//refresh if it is expired.
  return fetchData(token);
}
```

I think it'd better if I initialize data for all the tabs in one request, because I can catch only one refresh token expired and socket exception in single place.

```
fetchAllData()async{
  final token = await getToken();//refresh if it is expired.
  return fetchAllData(token);
}
```

How would you build logic for screen and requests like that? Is my approach is something similar to what you use?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use a Provider (https://pub.dev/packages/provider). By subscribing to the same Provider, you will be able to reuse the data you've once fetched. For instance, I've used this approach to provide to my App (at different places) the current user:

```
class UserModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  User _currentUser;

  void setUser(User user) {
    _currentUser = user;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<User> getUser(BuildContext context) async {
    if (_currentUser == null) {
      _currentUser = await getUserRequest(context, hasRedirect: false);
    }
    return _currentUser;
  }
}
```

Hope it will fit your needs !

Comment: I use bloc for state management, in my question I want to know how to deal with token requests. Create bloc which provide token? I think it's not a good solution but still interesting how people cope with it.

Comment: Personally, I would go for a block, yes. Similar to my provider, I will maybe take advantage of the flutter_secure_storage plugin (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage) to save this token to make my queries without always fetching the token. As soon as my API returns a 401, I would then redo the fetch. But I don't see any better way to do this for now

Answer (score 0):

You can add your fetchAllData method to the initState of the widget that holds all of the tabbed widgets.  Then, you can you can pass the relevant data to the contructors of each of the tabbed widgets.  Not the best solution,  but it should work.

I'd still recommend Provider.  State management systems are not all inclusive, nor are exclusive.  Depending on how your state is presented your could use more than one state management system.  Helll, the bloc library already includes the provider library.